# Ember.State has been moved into a plugin

Tags: ember.js

I am referencing the latest ember build but get this error in the console. Why is that?

```
Uncaught Error: Ember.State has been moved into a plugin: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-states
```

This is the code in the latest build that brings up this error:

```
/**
Ember

@module ember
*/

function throwWithMessage(msg) {
  return function() {
    throw new Ember.Error(msg);
  };
}
```

Comment: Just download and include the plugin as mentioned. The problem isn't happening in the code you supplied, it's just where Ember throws it's exception and thus where the error console will show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the message says, Ember.State is now in a plugin. This is the new repository https://github.com/emberjs/ember-states

You can get the lastest build [here](http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-states/latest/ember-states.js)

Make sure to include ember-states.js after your ember.js, so it will override the version that throw errors.